# Como utilizar imagenes de imgur

Tags: html

Buens tardes

Cuando intento utilizar una imagen de imgur simplemente no me carga, cuando utilizo la etiqueta
 `<img src="https://i.imgur.com/gTOmpY4.png"/>`
no me carga, el link si es directo a la imagen, cuando uso cualquier otro link ajeno a imgur si me deja.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay ninguna restriccion que exista el no poder cargar la imagen desde el dominio que comentas,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Ejemplo cargando una imagen desde el dominio imgur.com!</p>
<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/gTOmpY4.png"/>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema puede deberse a que el dominio se encuentra bloqueado, probablemente te encuentras dentro de un proxy.**